# How can i clear and load RepeatBox?

Tags: smartface.io

I tried to refresh the RepeatBox but i could not do it. I try to clear and load the RepeatBox while i am deleting a row in the RepeatBox.

repeatBox.refresh() does not work.  Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please add some code of what you've tried so far? All the best,

Comment: var xdeletel = new SMF.Net.WebClient({
URL : "http://www.xxx/webService.asmx",
httpMethod : "POST",
requestHeaders : [
"Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
],
onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) {
    alert("row is deleted");
    Pages.Page1.RepeatBox1.refresh();
},
onServerError : function (e) {
alert(e.message);
},
//requestString : requestString,
responseHandling : SMF.Net.ResponseHandling.forceText,
timeoutInterval : 120
});

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the repeatBox? Are you getting the alert("row is deleted")?

Comment: Yes i am getting the alert("row is deleted"). I am sure. Record is deleting from the table. I checked it.